# Spring cloud: Ribbon and HTTPS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We want to use HTTPS for our microservices communication based on Feign and Ribbon. The services are based on spring boot and tomcat is correctly setup. The instances are registered with the HTTPS URL and securePort enabled on Eureka. However, when we call another microservice via Feign then the underlying Ribbon doesn't recognizes the protocol and falls back to HTTP. I could solve that problem by adding the protocol to the FeignClient annotation like this:

```
    @FeignClient("https://users")
```

But it seem that the Zuul proxy and the Hystrix/Turbine which are also using Ribbon internally have the same HTTP fallback problem. Is there any way to configure Ribbon centrally to use HTTPS as default or use the **securePort** setting of the registred eureka instance?

Eureka instance configuration:

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.securePort = ${server.port}
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled = true  
eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled = false 
eureka.instance.metadataMap.hostname = ${eureka.instance.hostname}
eureka.instance.metadataMap.securePort = ${server.port}
eureka.instance.homePageUrl = https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl = https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/admin/info
```

With these settings it looks in Eureka like the service runs on HTTPS. The Zuul proxy runs fine, but uses the HTTP URL to call the service. You have to enable SSL in Spring Boots embedded Tomcat by providing a server certificate in a keystore:

```
server.ssl.key-store=server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=<pw>
server.ssl.keyStoreType=jks
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
server.ssl.key-password=<pw>
```

Tomcat than only runs on HTTPS and the HTTP port is blocked, but than I get: `localhost:8081 failed to respond` because a HTTP URL is used to call the service. By setting `ribbon.IsSecure=true` the users service url is correctly generated, but the Ribbon loadbalancer fails to lookup the users service in Eureka: `Load balancer does not have available server for client: users`. I aslo tried to set `users.ribbon.IsSecure=true` in the zuul proxy only, but still get the same error.

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: user
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468)
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7304)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:112)
at rx.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:81)
at rx.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:59)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:77)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:41)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:30)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7393)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:441)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102)
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonCommand.forward(RibbonCommand.java:129)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonCommand.run(RibbonCommand.java:103)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonCommand.run(RibbonCommand.java:1)
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
```

Comment: If you use eureka's `securePort`, that should be the port registered with eureka.

Comment: I confirm spencergibb's comment: we are not having any problem with ZUUL forwarding to services listening to 443 (make sure you enabled the secure port in your client with 'eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true')

However, I wonder if you shouldn't always use "http" instead of "https" in your @FeignClient annotation whatever the actual port your instances are listening.

Comment: The service is registered with eureka correctly I guess. We are using the following properties: 
`eureka.instance.securePort = ${server.port}
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled = true
eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled = false`
but still getting `com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: <host>:8081 failed to respond`

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with other stuff, but today I could debug this a bit further.  I think the magic lies in `LoadBalancerContext.deriveSchemeAndPortFromPartialUri()`. When I set `ribbon.IsSecure=true` than the URL calculation for the service is correct in `reconstructURIWithServer()` like `https://<host>:8081/users/1`. But than the service lookup in Eureka fails in `LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer()` because the URL is `https://<host>:443` and not `https://<host>:8761`. I'll continue debugging next week ...

Comment: No luck so far. We configured Eureka listening on 443, but get now `Load balancer does not have available server for client: users` so it seems that that `LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer()` can't lookup an user service instance. We want to run all microservices on HTTPS and several of them on one host differentiated by ports. So it wouldn't be an option for us to use the default port. Any ideas how to set this up?

Comment: I think the URL generation for the Turbine Dashboard is in SpringClusterMonitor.getUrlPath() which creates at the end a HTTP URL. Can cluster monitor method somehow overwritten and a injected as a new bean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We solved the zuul proxy problem now by setting

```
ribbon.IsSecure=true
eureka.instance.secureVirtualHostName=${spring.application.name}
```

so that all services are also in the secure virtual hosts pool in `com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications`. That helps the discovery process to find the instances in eureka.

However, the Hystrix dashboard has still a similar problem

Comment: where should these 2 properties be added ? i added these 2 properties to the Spring Boot App which is HTTPS enabled and registered to Eureka. When Zuul tries to route the request to it, looks like Zuul is still trying to use the HTTP url for it.  Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:151) ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]

Comment: I have added these 2 properties to my Zuul Route application's yaml file as well but, still facing the same issue. org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem trying to configure Zuul proxy to use Ribbon to connect to micro services running on https: RibbonRoutingFilter is looking at requestURI and create RestClient when run method is executed. I configured Eureka to run on http though. It is the underlying https microservice registered on Eureka cannot be accessed by Ribbon.

http works perfectly with simple zuul routes set up.

Comment: yes, this got resolved by specifying ribbon isSecure and implement a custom socketfactory to accept the cert you want.
`
instance:
    securePort: ${server.port}
    secureVirtualHostName: ${spring.application.name}
    metadatamap:
      instanceId: "${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${server.port}}"
    preferIpAddress: true
    securePortEnabled: true
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false

ribbon:
  IsSecure: true
  CustomSSLSocketFactoryClassName: YourCustomSocketFactory
`

Answer (score 0):

After adding *isSecure:true* also there might be some possibility for an unsuccessful handshake, faced this once and I resolve this by adding the Truststore like below

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="//location of.JKS file " and
> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="valid password".

Thes one helped me to fix the HTTPS handshake issues